# Not able to scrape a website, some issue with post request

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** some data from https://tradingtick.com/options/callvsput.php. I have used the header & form-data given in the network tab without much success.

Here is my code using python requests library.

```
url = 'https://tradingtick.com/options/callvsput.php'


headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',  'Connection': 'keep-alive',  'Content-Length': '134',  'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',  'DNT': '1',  'Host': 'tradingtick.com',  'Origin': 'https://tradingtick.com',  'Referer': 'https://tradingtick.com/options/callvsput.php',  'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"',  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.64'}

payload = {
    "dataType": "\"hist\"",
    "endStrike": "\"34800\"",
    "hDate": "\"2021-07-02\"",
    "range": "true",
    "startStrike": "\"34800\"",
    "type": "\"data\"",
    "underlying": "\"BANKNIFTY\""}
 r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

OUTPUT:

```
In [72]: r.text
Out[72]: '\n'
```

While the response tab on browser shows that it is supposed to return a json object containing data displayed in the chart on the browser. C

Could someone please help me by pointing out my mistake ? Thank you !

Comment: FYI it’s scrape not scrap. To scrap means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from server, use `json=` parameter:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://tradingtick.com/options/callvsput.php"

payload = {
    "dataType": "hist",
    "endStrike": "37000",
    "hDate": "2021-07-02",
    "range": True,
    "startStrike": "33000",
    "type": "data",
    "underlying": "BANKNIFTY",
}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()
# pretty print the data:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    "[{\"x\":\"02-07 09:10\",\"y\":\"6704850\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"02-07 15:30\",\"y\":\"9949875\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"02-07 09:10\",\"y\":\"4627525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"02-07 15:30\",\"y\":\"7585225\",\"type\":\"PE\"}]",
    "[{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:10\",\"y\":\"6704850\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:15\",\"y\":\"6704850\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:20\",\"y\":\"7428425\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:25\",\"y\":\"8827225\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:30\",\"y\":\"9545125\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:35\",\"y\":\"9843525\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:40\",\"y\":\"10247750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:45\",\"y\":\"10584800\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:50\",\"y\":\"10812225\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:55\",\"y\":\"11055975\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:00\",\"y\":\"11339575\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:05\",\"y\":\"11464125\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:10\",\"y\":\"11660625\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:15\",\"y\":\"11624000\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:20\",\"y\":\"11721075\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:25\",\"y\":\"11738100\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:30\",\"y\":\"11822750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:35\",\"y\":\"11937250\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:40\",\"y\":\"11875275\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:45\",\"y\":\"11905750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:50\",\"y\":\"12055750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:55\",\"y\":\"12181600\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:00\",\"y\":\"12256325\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:05\",\"y\":\"12317450\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:10\",\"y\":\"12355075\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:15\",\"y\":\"12480125\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:20\",\"y\":\"12533675\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:25\",\"y\":\"12496975\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:30\",\"y\":\"12508850\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:35\",\"y\":\"12546700\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:40\",\"y\":\"12453625\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:45\",\"y\":\"12408600\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:50\",\"y\":\"12445200\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:55\",\"y\":\"12473000\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:00\",\"y\":\"12450550\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:05\",\"y\":\"12394100\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:10\",\"y\":\"12301100\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:15\",\"y\":\"12299025\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:20\",\"y\":\"12327625\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:25\",\"y\":\"12296525\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:30\",\"y\":\"12357550\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:35\",\"y\":\"12264850\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:40\",\"y\":\"12358600\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:45\",\"y\":\"12402250\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:50\",\"y\":\"12418000\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:55\",\"y\":\"12429875\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:00\",\"y\":\"12285275\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:05\",\"y\":\"11514050\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:10\",\"y\":\"11464225\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:15\",\"y\":\"11515700\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:20\",\"y\":\"11886425\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:25\",\"y\":\"12082300\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:30\",\"y\":\"12119650\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:35\",\"y\":\"12191600\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:40\",\"y\":\"12256550\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:45\",\"y\":\"12203225\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:55\",\"y\":\"12267875\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:00\",\"y\":\"12321375\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:05\",\"y\":\"12404150\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:10\",\"y\":\"12480950\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:15\",\"y\":\"12460350\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:20\",\"y\":\"12448800\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:25\",\"y\":\"12346675\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:30\",\"y\":\"12308050\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:35\",\"y\":\"12231425\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:40\",\"y\":\"12196475\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:45\",\"y\":\"12134000\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:50\",\"y\":\"12148500\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:55\",\"y\":\"12104975\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:00\",\"y\":\"11983575\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:05\",\"y\":\"11855825\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:10\",\"y\":\"11654750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:15\",\"y\":\"11509750\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:20\",\"y\":\"10947325\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:25\",\"y\":\"10242200\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:30\",\"y\":\"9949875\",\"type\":\"CE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:10\",\"y\":\"4627525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:15\",\"y\":\"4627525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:20\",\"y\":\"5146275\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:25\",\"y\":\"6343150\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:30\",\"y\":\"6871175\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:35\",\"y\":\"7231975\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:40\",\"y\":\"7842050\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:45\",\"y\":\"8126225\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:50\",\"y\":\"8282750\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:55\",\"y\":\"8533500\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:00\",\"y\":\"8762800\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:05\",\"y\":\"8932375\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:10\",\"y\":\"9097025\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:15\",\"y\":\"9227350\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:20\",\"y\":\"9223325\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:25\",\"y\":\"9279675\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:30\",\"y\":\"9439825\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:35\",\"y\":\"9592700\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:40\",\"y\":\"9704525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:45\",\"y\":\"9732475\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:50\",\"y\":\"9624900\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:55\",\"y\":\"9613400\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:00\",\"y\":\"9706525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:05\",\"y\":\"9722000\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:10\",\"y\":\"9742975\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:15\",\"y\":\"9828825\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:20\",\"y\":\"9831100\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:25\",\"y\":\"9747400\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:30\",\"y\":\"9778100\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:35\",\"y\":\"9774625\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:40\",\"y\":\"9760975\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:45\",\"y\":\"9781525\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:50\",\"y\":\"9793475\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:55\",\"y\":\"9817825\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:00\",\"y\":\"9868475\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:05\",\"y\":\"9931450\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:10\",\"y\":\"10016575\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:15\",\"y\":\"10061475\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:20\",\"y\":\"10086900\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:25\",\"y\":\"10143900\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:30\",\"y\":\"10177150\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:35\",\"y\":\"10260575\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:40\",\"y\":\"10318175\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:45\",\"y\":\"10362150\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:50\",\"y\":\"10451925\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:55\",\"y\":\"10455500\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:00\",\"y\":\"10498575\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:05\",\"y\":\"10551675\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:10\",\"y\":\"10612375\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:15\",\"y\":\"10623050\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:20\",\"y\":\"10714400\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:25\",\"y\":\"10740825\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:30\",\"y\":\"10702850\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:35\",\"y\":\"10688800\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:40\",\"y\":\"10662700\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:45\",\"y\":\"10532575\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:55\",\"y\":\"10395625\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:00\",\"y\":\"10358725\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:05\",\"y\":\"10226650\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:10\",\"y\":\"10135400\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:15\",\"y\":\"10184600\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:20\",\"y\":\"10249900\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:25\",\"y\":\"10159825\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:30\",\"y\":\"10197025\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:35\",\"y\":\"10271500\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:40\",\"y\":\"10214775\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:45\",\"y\":\"10143575\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:50\",\"y\":\"10039275\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:55\",\"y\":\"9860975\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:00\",\"y\":\"9807250\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:05\",\"y\":\"9557125\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:10\",\"y\":\"9286975\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:15\",\"y\":\"9161000\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:20\",\"y\":\"8598650\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:25\",\"y\":\"7964650\",\"type\":\"PE\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:30\",\"y\":\"7585225\",\"type\":\"PE\"}]",
    "Jul 02, 15:30",
    "08-Jul",
    "[{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:30\",\"y\":\"34971.05\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:10\",\"y\":\"34853.05\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:25\",\"y\":\"34968.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:20\",\"y\":\"34943.95\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:15\",\"y\":\"34934.95\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:10\",\"y\":\"34919.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:05\",\"y\":\"34934.10\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 15:00\",\"y\":\"34884.25\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:55\",\"y\":\"34887.05\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:50\",\"y\":\"34904.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:45\",\"y\":\"34905.15\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:40\",\"y\":\"34911.45\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:35\",\"y\":\"34950.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:30\",\"y\":\"34955.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:25\",\"y\":\"34936.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:20\",\"y\":\"34841.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:15\",\"y\":\"34862.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:10\",\"y\":\"34865.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:05\",\"y\":\"34812.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 14:00\",\"y\":\"34812.65\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:55\",\"y\":\"34853.45\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:45\",\"y\":\"34919.85\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:40\",\"y\":\"34893.55\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:35\",\"y\":\"34925.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:30\",\"y\":\"34940.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:25\",\"y\":\"34933.85\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:20\",\"y\":\"34925.45\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:15\",\"y\":\"34989.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:10\",\"y\":\"35000.50\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:05\",\"y\":\"35023.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 13:00\",\"y\":\"35023.05\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:55\",\"y\":\"34945.20\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:50\",\"y\":\"34944.90\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:45\",\"y\":\"34944.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:40\",\"y\":\"34924.70\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:35\",\"y\":\"34944.55\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:30\",\"y\":\"34938.45\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:25\",\"y\":\"34910.55\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:20\",\"y\":\"34943.80\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:15\",\"y\":\"34910.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:10\",\"y\":\"34887.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:05\",\"y\":\"34921.60\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 12:00\",\"y\":\"34883.50\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:55\",\"y\":\"34860.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:50\",\"y\":\"34850.60\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:45\",\"y\":\"34871.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:40\",\"y\":\"34842.45\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:35\",\"y\":\"34857.65\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:30\",\"y\":\"34863.55\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:25\",\"y\":\"34862.85\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:20\",\"y\":\"34845.55\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:15\",\"y\":\"34845.20\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:10\",\"y\":\"34832.10\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:05\",\"y\":\"34830.25\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 11:00\",\"y\":\"34828.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:55\",\"y\":\"34825.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:50\",\"y\":\"34816.70\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:45\",\"y\":\"34852.95\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:40\",\"y\":\"34924.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:35\",\"y\":\"34897.30\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:30\",\"y\":\"34923.10\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:25\",\"y\":\"34889.90\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:20\",\"y\":\"34871.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:15\",\"y\":\"34906.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:10\",\"y\":\"34854.05\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:05\",\"y\":\"34855.65\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 10:00\",\"y\":\"34847.90\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:55\",\"y\":\"34841.30\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:50\",\"y\":\"34773.60\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:45\",\"y\":\"34820.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:40\",\"y\":\"34805.00\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:35\",\"y\":\"34840.70\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:30\",\"y\":\"34812.35\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:25\",\"y\":\"34775.65\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:20\",\"y\":\"34857.25\"},{\"x\":\"2021-07-02 09:15\",\"y\":\"34868.45\"}]"
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Much appreciated.